# Call-by-Reference or Call-by-value in EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

Let's say i have an EJB `FooBean` which has in case:

1. Remote Interface
2. Local Interface
3. No Interface View

I call a method of `FooBean` (through an interface for case 1,2) from an EJB-Client and pass an object parameter `SimpleObject obj` through it. The bean method change some property. `obj.setProperty("Hello")` . In which cases is it call-by-value, in which cases is it call-by-reference, when:

1. EJB Client is in same EAR Application
2. EJB Client is in the same EJB-Container
3. EJB Client is remote

   The Client property value was ("Ciao"). What will the client reveive?

Comment: @Peter: this isn't true if the object is serialized and then unserialized during the process (like in remote EJB).

Comment: Andy, please don't use [java] tag as long as your Java EE related question is not demonstrable using a plain Java application class with main() method (moreover, in such case the relevance of Java EE related tags is questionable). Otherwise you will get knee-jerk responses.

Comment: @BalusC correct.  The library you call can copy the content of the data, or it could pass a proxy reference and be effectively pass by reference.  In this case it depends on the details of the library.